# Whats the etiquette when you answer the OPs question, but they change it in the comments

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, etiquette

I was helping a user answer a question [Parse login not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124717/parse-login-not-working-properly/25126634#25126634) but they were not very clear what they were after.

After speaking to them in the comments it was clear that his question had changed, but they didn't update it. - What is the best cause of action? Should I edit the question after having a better understanding of what the OP required?

Comment: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)